# VB6: How to wait for a command to execute

Tags: shell, vb6, exec

The code I have below runs without error.

But I need it to wait until the process has been killed at this line: `WshShell.Exec "TASKKILL /F /IM " & EngineRun.ProcessID` before showing the msgbox that it has been terminated.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell As Object
Dim EngineRun As Object

Sub main()

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set EngineRun = WshShell.Exec("notepad.exe")

MsgBox EngineRun.ProcessID

WshShell.Exec "TASKKILL /F /IM " & EngineRun.ProcessID

MsgBox EngineRun.ProcessID & (" terminated")

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use the `Run` method instead?  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx).  It supports a bWaitOnReturn parameter:

```
object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

So your code would look like:

```
WshShell.Run "TASKKILL /F /IM " & EngineRun.ProcessID,4 , True
```

Comment: Changed to `WshShell.run "TASKKILL /F /IM " & EngineRun.ProcessID, , True` and we have a winner! I tried a different  method using Do...Until, but yours is far cleaner and simpler. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

Do things properly.